# If I test in Chrome and Firefox on Windows, why would I need to on Mac?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, testing, browser, cross-browser

If I'm developing something for the web and I've already done functional testing in Chrome, Firefox, and IE on Windows do I really need to do the same on OS X? Are the browsers (Chrome and Firefox) widely different in how they work between each operating system that separate tests are needed in each browser for each OS?

Comment: s/windows/linux

s/mac/windows

One 'notice'able difference is the font face (which is different on different operating systems). But as long as you're specifying font-face/family, you shouldn't run into that trouble.

looking forward for a detailed explanation if there is indeed a difference, and how that'd affect the 'web-view'.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to. By and large there will be no difference between the two on the same browsers. You may *rarely* find quirks that differ slightly, but I've never come across any.

Answer (score 0):

I posed this question on Reddit and Hacker News. Here's a brief roll-up of the highlights of responses:

1. There appears to be consensus that the main difference you're likely to experience has to do with font types rendering (types render more smoothly on OS X and iOS).
2. Many suggested that the majority of what you see between Windows and OS X versions of the browsers is the same, with only subtle differences in the user agent based on the OS design (e.g., native radio buttons, scrollbars, etc.).  This is not exclusive to browsers but to all apps running on each OS. Also, feature support in browsers doesn't vary between OS, i.e., if it's only a partially-supported feature in Firefox, it's that way on all platforms.
3. There were suggestions that, given the strong preference for developing on the Mac platform, it makes more sense to test on OS X's versions of Chrome and Firefox (and Safari) and remotely test IE (e.g., modern.ie, BrowerStack, Sauce Labs, etc.) Using a cross-browser testing suite like BrowserStack doesn't preclude the possibility of including mobile browsers (for later discussion).

Sources: [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/345n79/if_i_test_in_chrome_and_firefox_on_windows_why/), [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9452551)